# Есть ли активно развивающиеся минималистичные веб фреймворки для питона?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, framework

Последняя стабильная версия фласка в июне 13 года. Такое настораживает. Существуют ли веб фрейморки, которые не были бы завязаны на одном человеке, с активной разработкой? Что вы используете для простых веб приложений на питоне?

Comment: В любой непонятной ситуации использую 7 мегабайтный монструозный [Django.](https://www.djangoproject.com) Стрелять из ракетницы по воробьям это весело.

Comment: 2igumnov Вот как раз и не хочется монстра :( На руби мне не понравилось в итоге работать с рельсами. Из мира node.js очень нравится легковесный express.js. И хочется чего-то похожего в питоне.

Comment: Почему вас пугает монстр?

Comment: Последнее обновление Flask на гитхабе — 2 дня назад.